# Answer from Name server that return 127.0.0.1 for A record

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-server

When resolving `zapworld.com`, I got the following response from the TLD server (`g.gtld-servers.net.`):

```
zapworld.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns2.developyour.net.deleted.gandi.net.
zapworld.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns1.developyour.net.deleted.gandi.net.
```

but `ns2.developyour.net.deleted.gandi.net.` points to `127.0.0.1`:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
ns2.developyour.net.deleted.gandi.net.  86400   IN  A   127.0.0.1
```

It looks like the domain does not exist anymore, but why does `ns2.developyour.net.deleted.gandi.net.` to `127.0.0.1`? Would it not be simpler to just return `NXDOMAIN` for those kind of request?

Also, what a recursive resolver is supposed to do when it faces this kind of answer? I do not find a RFC that covers this case?

Comment: Hmmm...not sure I understand well what you want. You actually must do that pointing if you run an internal DNS.

Comment: I'm not running an internal DNS. I am running a recursive resolver, and 1 of the incoming query is zapworld.com. During the phases of the resolution (root, tld), I got 127.0.0.1 as IP for the name server. At this point, I'm not sure what behavior a recursive resolver should have with that kind of answer. Should it stop and return NXDOMAIN? should it something else? I do not find a RFC that could address that issue.

Comment: Some registries check nameservers before allowing a domain update. If the nameserver used would not properly resolve, the registry could refuse the change, hence simpler not to return NXDOMAIN here. Also the setup you observe happens when a registrar needs to delete a domain name but can't because host objects under it are used by other registrars. To break the cycle they rename the host objects.

Answer (score 0):

Are you *writing* a recursive resolver? You should not expect every possible scenario to be covered in RFCs, especially when they deal with people doing unexpected things. While they try to cover everything, this is impossible. You should do something reasonable given the circumstances.

What I expect to happen with real nameservers is that the recursive resolver will get 127.0.0.1 as the nameserver for the domain, and then send a query directly to that server (itself) with the RD bit cleared, expecting an authoritative response. The nameserver, finding it is not authoritative for the domain, ought to send a REFUSED response. I queried several public recursive resolvers for an address record in this domain. Mostly I received REFUSED responses, though a few returned SERVFAIL.

That said, this sort of behavior on the part of the DNS administrator of that domain is not very good. It puts unnecessary (albeit minimal) load on servers that do not need it. If the domain really were "deleted" then they could simply not serve any DNS records at all, or only an SOA record.

Comment: Yes, I am writing a recursive resolver. Thank you, it makes sense, I also have seen recursive resolver like google returns a REFUSED code. Regarding the RFC, I thought I have seen before a RFC explaining what to do in case of private IP address as answer, but impossible to figure out which one was it.

Comment: " If the domain really were "deleted"" It is more complicated than that. With current systems and size of comment box here, if registrar A has dom1.example but ns1.dom1.example created in the past and host used by registrar B for dom2.example, then registrar A can NOT delete domain dom1.example because of existence of ns1.domain1.example used by other registrar. It has to convince other registrar to update the domain OR, alternate strategy that works, it renames (when registries allow it) the hostname of the host object to something outside of dom1.example, which can then be deleted as domain.